# monero blocks /min , too many, should be just 1 every 2 min

Tags: monerod, block-reward

is this ok to have so many blocks / min?

1686205 2018-10-19 17:44:40 (10 minutes ago)    7542    4   92228410a92dc14bad88ef8baac0af83c37bf1526fb64b0a76357989fc8a6f76
1686204 2018-10-19 17:44:15 (10 minutes ago)    2111    2   1493ad878a7514f45c62c9a07cc12515d281baf57b1770d2a5d6601e2d63280b
1686203 2018-10-19 17:44:03 (10 minutes ago)    2910    2   16d4d4c97b4d1cdf053374ee62fb4f7be357ca5ed339fb3ce150ff96a8d6d35b
1686202 2018-10-19 17:43:54 (10 minutes ago)    143 1   6387f72c34ab910bf9c379311c87fe61352cd36cf246dce50c11b04455656e66
1686201 2018-10-19 17:43:50 (10 minutes ago)    16284   5   85150117f737edf0517a308ff88f98da746ce6855cf39aae9de22d78b31b1586

why not 1 block every 2 min?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has just been a fork. Not everyone updated before or just after the fork. Difficulty adjustment algorithm not settled yet to reflect. Block times, as a result are not yet smoothed out to the ideal time of 2 minutes. It will settle, just be patient.

Comment: To add to this, block times are average block times. A specific set may be more or less than 2 minutes.